# Wordpress: float form on right

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float

I am working on this website http://m-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/ and at the end of the page, as you can see there is a Booking calendar with a form. Is it possible to float the Calendar **left** and the Form **right** via CSS?

Comment: Is this form is generate by plugin? you are able to do changes in plugin or not?

Comment: @Deepaksaini yeah is generated by the same plugin of the calendar. Is http://wpbookingcalendar.com/ and yeah, via CSS i can change the color and the size, so i think that is possible to float it.

Comment: please add this is your css .bk_calendar_frame.months_num_in_row_.cal_month_num_1 {
  float: left;
  height: 340px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add few things in the class.

```
.bk_calendar_frame.months_num_in_row_.cal_month_num_1 { 
           float: left; height: 340px; margin-right: 50px;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add separate div for control-group which make to separate the calendar and the form.
2. CSS Code:

   .bk_calendar_frame {
      float: left;
   }
3. CSS Code:

   .parent-div .control-group {
       float: right
   }